# Why do I cannot user createCriteria method which I define in ManagerBase class?

Tags: java, hibernate, entity, observablelist

I dont know why i cannot call getAll() class in ManagerBase class from UserDAO, but with other class it still be ok

Hibernate code here

```
protected Session getCurrentSession() throws Exception {
    if (session == null){ //check session null
        if (sessionFactory == null){ //build sessionFactory if it null
            if(sessionFactoryConfigPath == null || sessionFactoryConfigPath.equals("")){
                sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            }else{
                sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure(this.sessionFactoryConfigPath).buildSessionFactory();
            }
        }
        session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
    return session;
}
```

ManagerBase code

```
public abstract class ManagerBase<T> extends HibernateUtil {


    private Class<T> persistentClass;

    public ManagerBase() throws Exception {
        super();
        this.persistentClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments().getClass();
    }

    public ManagerBase(String sessionFactoryConfigPath) throws Exception {
        super(sessionFactoryConfigPath);
        this.persistentClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments().getClass();
    }

    public Class<T> getPersistentClass() {
        return this.persistentClass;
    }
public List<T> getAll() {
    List<T> list = null;
    try {
        beginTransaction();
        list = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(this.persistentClass).list();
        commitAndClose();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("getAll Error \n" + ex);
    }
    return list;
}
```

UserDAO code here.....

code

```
public class UserDAO extends ManagerBase<User> {

    public UserDAO() throws Exception {

    }

    public List<User> getAllUser() {
        try {
            List<User> user = getAll();
            return user;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Get All User Error \n" + ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Any body please help me, in the console board that show only Begin and commit and it doesnt has any HQL code.

Comment: How this.persistentClass is defined?

Comment: Please see in ManagerBase above:
<pre>private Class<T> persistentClass;<code>

Comment: Please help me :(